# Can somebody suggest me c++ library for serial port communicaiton which works on x86 and x86_64 versions of OS?

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

Can somebody suggest me c++ library for serial port communicaiton which works on x86 and x86_64 versions of OS ? I have used Java  SerialIO but it crashed on x86_64 versions.

Comment: I know it's not C++, but you could try PySerial for Python. It's pretty easy to use and it works for both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: @Kenji I would prefer if is possible C++ because I need to use QT for GUI, but if I don;t find anythung I can use Python. What then to use for GUI in Python ? I don't have much experience with Python.

Comment: there is also pyQt - port of QT to Python

Comment: I've been using GTK, but QT is nice too. Python is not a particularly difficult language to learn, so you might wanna have a look at it first. The interpreter really helps when prototyping (e.g. when you're exploring PySerial's API).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want c++ then [QextSerialPort](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) is your choise.

Answer (score 1):

On linux ,maybe, u'll try "termios"

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int tcgetattr(int fd, struct termios *termios_p); 

int tcsetattr(int fd, int optional_actions, const struct termios *termios_p); 

int tcsendbreak(int fd, int duration); 

int tcdrain(int fd); 

int tcflush(int fd, int queue_selector); 

int tcflow(int fd, int action); 

void cfmakeraw(struct termios *termios_p); 

speed_t cfgetispeed(const struct termios *termios_p); 

speed_t cfgetospeed(const struct termios *termios_p); 

int cfsetispeed(struct termios *termios_p, speed_t speed); 

int cfsetospeed(struct termios *termios_p, speed_t speed);
```

Comment: This answer isn't actually related to serial communications, at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the serial port interface of boost::asio

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/serial_ports.html